# Can't change node version using nvm

Tags: node.js, nvm

I need to upgrade my current node version (v10.16.3) to a version higher than v12,

I tried `nvm ls` `nvm use --lts` in the cmd with admin rights, but I still get the same version when I do `node-v`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of --lts specify version you want to use, i.e. `nvm use 16.13.2`

Also remember to install it, if you dont see it in `nvm ls` (`nvm install 16.13.2`)

Comment: ok it's all done but when I do node -v I still get my old version displayed

Comment: @VersifiXion - maybe try to run the command line as administrator